# Adding columns to a map function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So Tanaike built me a script that copies a value in one column into another column and goes down rows until it meets another value in the original column, then it proceeds to copy that one. This is great for getting a concatenated string for vlookups on outline-formatted Google Sheets.

The one question I have remaining regarding this: is how to add more columns to the newly produced rows at the end of the sheet.

Here is Tanaike's script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // or ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();
  var n = "";
  var res = values.map(function(row) {
    if (row[1].indexOf("Place") != -1) {  // Modified
      n = row[1];
      return row;
    }
    return [n, row[1], row[2]]; // Modified
  });
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 3, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);

//  ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

I'm not familiar with a few of the operations in here so I tried to guess as to how to expand the column values it pulled down (currently it goes to C), but I kept encountering data errors.

All I would like is for it to do the same thing it's already doing, but with additional columns being pulled down into the generated rows, where B's value is now copied over into A at every row until it encounters a new value in B that has "Place" in it's name.

Here is what the format looks like originally:
[image: Original Google Sheets Format]

And here it is with Tanaike's script (produced at the bottom of the sheet): 
[image: New Format]

It works great, I just need it to bring down some of the other values with it such as the "Code", "Earning", "Hours", and "Amount" columns. This is all so I can concatenate them into a unique string for some values I need to import on another sheet. Thank you for any and all help in resolving this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just add row [#] to line 11 then increase line 4 `optNumColumns` by that amount +3. Thank you again Tanaike!